# How to show the repeated value as NULL in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, linq-to-sql

I have a query which gives result as below, how to replace duplicate values with NULL

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    word.lemma,
    synset.definition,
    synset.pos,
    sampletable.sample
FROM
    word 
        LEFT JOIN
    sense ON word.wordid = sense.wordid
        LEFT JOIN
    synset ON sense.synsetid = synset.synsetid
        LEFT JOIN
    sampletable ON synset.synsetid = sampletable.synsetid
WHERE
    word.lemma = 'good'
```

**Result:**
[image]

**Required Result:** all the *greyed out* results as NULL

[image]

Comment: each row has different sample , so they won't be considered as  duplicate

Comment: so there is no way of getting distinct results ? @cchajar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is the type of transformation that is generally better done at the application level.  The reason is that it presupposes that the result set is in a particular order -- and you seem to be assuming this even with no `order by` clause.

Second, it is often simpler in the application.

However, in MySQL 8+, it is not that hard.  You can do:

```
SELECT w.lemma,
       (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY w.lemma, ss.definition ORDER BY st.sample) = 1
             THEN ss.definition
        END) as definition,
       ss.pos,
       st.sample
FROM word w LEFT JOIN
     sense s
     ON w.wordid = s.wordid LEFT JOIN
     synset ss
     ON s.synsetid = ss.synsetid LEFT JOIN
     sampletable st
     ON ss.synsetid = st.synsetid
WHERE w.lemma = 'good'
ORDER BY w.lemma, ss.definition, st.sample;
```

For this to work reliably, the outer `ORDER BY` clause needs to be compatible with the `ORDER BY` for the window function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mysql 8 try with Rank().. As I didn't have your table or data couldn't test this query.

```
SELECT
    word.lemma
    ,case when r = 1 synset.definition else null end as definition
    ,synset.pos
    ,sampletable.sample
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        word.lemma
        ,synset.definition
        ,synset.pos
        ,sampletable.sample
        ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY synset.definition ORDER BY synset.definition) r
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            word.lemma,
            synset.definition,
            synset.pos,
            sampletable.sample
        FROM
            word 
                LEFT JOIN
            sense ON word.wordid = sense.wordid
                LEFT JOIN
            synset ON sense.synsetid = synset.synsetid
                LEFT JOIN
            sampletable ON synset.synsetid = sampletable.synsetid
        WHERE
            word.lemma = 'good'
        ) t
    )t1;
```